# How can i wait for data until it get received in Node.js from a TCP server while GET request is sent by the user?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I want to send a hello message to a C++ based server that is listening over port "9090" once the message is sent, the server will do some job or task that will take some time, so i don't want to leave the app.get(); function block, how can i do that until getting a data from server then send back to the user as a response?

Basically what  i want is to not reply the user, stay inside the loop while(close_connection_flag ==  false) until it set to true to leave the loop (until i get a tcp-reply data) then leave the loop and reply the user.

The code i have:

```
var net = require('net');
var tcp_client = new net.Socket();
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var close_connection_flag = false;
var flag_raised_by_server = '';


app.get('/', function(req, res) {

  tcp_client.on('connect', function(){
    console.log('[+] Connected.');
    tcp_client.write('HelloServerSideFrom:Client-Server');
  });

  while(close_connection_flag == false) {

    tcp_client.on('data', function(data) {

      switch(data){

        case 'HelloClientServerFrom:Server':
          close_connection_flag = true;
          break;
        case 'data-success':
          close_connection_flag = true;
          flag_raised_by_server = 'ds';
          break;
        case 'data-failure':
          close_connection_flag = true;
          flag_raised_by_server = 'df';
          break
        default:
          // do nothing.
          break;     

      }

    });

  }

  res.end('flag raised by server is: ' + flag_raised_by_server);
  tcp_client.destroy();
});
```

Note: I'm still newbie in `Node.js`, so if you could please provide some comments or explanation of the example code if you provide a one, thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't you have a `tcp_client.on('close')` event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood the question correctly, you want to send the HTTP response as soon as you've received a response from your downstream socket server.

First of all, the most important thing to consider: **Socket connections -- like almost everything -- in Node.JS are *asynchronous***.

This has some very important consequences:

1. The call to `tcp_client.on('data', ...)` **will not block your program execution** until you've received some data. It will simply register a callback function that will (may) be called at some later point in time and then continue your program.

   This means that if you register a callback in your TCP client and then send the HTTP reponse, the HTTP response will be sent *first*, and your callback will be called at some later point in time.
2. There is no need to use a while loop for polling on your socket; simply use the `tcp_client.on('data', ...)` method **once** to register a callback function that is called as soon data is read from the socket.

   As `tcp_client.on(...)` is asynchronous, it will return immediately; if you do so in a loop, you'll basically spin endlessly and constantly register new event listeners. So, **lose the `while(close_connection_flag == false)` loop!**
3. If you want to wait with your HTTP response until you've received data on your TCP socket, simply put your `res.end(...)` call *inside*  the `tcp_client` callback.

All in all, I'd suggest something like this:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {

  tcp_client.on('connect', function(){
    console.log('[+] Connected.');
    tcp_client.write('HelloServerSideFrom:Client-Server');
  });

  tcp_client.on('data', function(data) {
    var flag_raised_by_server;

    switch(data){

      case 'HelloClientServerFrom:Server':
        close_connection_flag = true;
        break;
      case 'data-success':
        close_connection_flag = true;
        flag_raised_by_server = 'ds';
        break;
      case 'data-failure':
        close_connection_flag = true;
        flag_raised_by_server = 'df';
        break
      default:
        // do nothing.
        break;     

    }

    if (flag_raised_by_server) {
      res.end('flag raised by server is: ' + flag_raised_by_server);
      tcp_client.destroy();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that might be it.

Comment: Sir, I have a problem that `flag_raised_by_server` variable is empty, and the response i'm getting is:

`flag raised by server is: `

it look that `flag_raised_by_server` is not initialized inside the switch case block, why?

Comment: In that case you might want to inspect what the TCP server actually responds with; try starting with a `console.log(data)` in your callback to see if the server actually sends the expected response. Also, I've adjusted my code example to send the HTTP response only when `flag_raised_by_server` is actually set. Maybe that helps, too.

Comment: Yes you're right, i got the tcp relpy as:

<Buffer 74 65 73 74 0a>

Comment: Ah yes, that's a raw byte buffer. You should be able to convert it to a regular string using [`data.toString()`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_tostring_encoding_start_end).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting `close_connection_flag` to true, just close the connection right there and return to the user. What you're doing here is creating a memory leak with an infinite amount of listeners on the `tcp_client`.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {

  tcp_client.on('connect', function(){
    console.log('[+] Connected.');
    tcp_client.write('HelloServerSideFrom:Client-Server');
  });

  tcp_client.on('data', function(data) {
    switch(data){

    case 'HelloClientServerFrom:Server':
      close_connection_flag = true;
      break;
    case 'data-success':
      close_connection_flag = true;
      flag_raised_by_server = 'ds';
      break;
    case 'data-failure':
      close_connection_flag = true;
      flag_raised_by_server = 'df';
      break
    default:
      // do nothing.
      break;     
    }

    if (close_connection_flag) {
      tcp_client.destroy();
      res.end('flag raised by server is: ' + flag_raised_by_server);
    }
  });
});
```